# react-query: don't refetch on an interval if there is an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I'm refetching an API on an interval, but I want to stop it if there is an error.

```
  const { status, data, error, isFetching } = useQuery(
    'todos',
    // only refetch if there is no error
    async () => {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/data')
      return res.data
    },
    {
      refetchInterval: intervalMs,
    }
  )
```

I could probably store the `status.isError` on a state variable and then use that with `enabled` but it seems a bit clunky. I couldn't find anything helpful going through the documentation.

Comment: I think thats what you are going to have to do. Im pretty sure one of the points of react-query is to keep refetching

Comment: @RichardHpa yeah, it's likely. I can probably create a hook that calls react-query and has a useState containing the error. Still, would prefer to know if there's something that doesn't introduce that complexity.

Comment: I had to do the same thing for a query I only want run once or manually retried

Comment: @RichardHpa why didn't you disable `retry`?

Comment: There is 4 different options you have to turn off retry, refetchOnMount, refetchOnReconnect, refetchOnWindowFocus that all need to be false. So just to prevent me having to write those multiple times I just made a hook for it

Comment: @RichardHpa as a person who comes from Apollo, settings that many just to disable auto retry are really surprising for me. I guess react-query really put refetching as first-class feature.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is indeed to do it via local state, but you don't need to disable the query if you don't want to - just setting the `refetchInterval` back to 0 might also be enough:

```
const [refetchInterval, setRefetchInterval] = useState(intervalMs)

useQuery(
  key,
  queryFn,
  {
    refetchInterval,
    onError: () => setRefetchInterval(0)
  }
)
```